# You must use infinite loops to efficiently reuse coroutine handles?

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20

Given the following coroutine format:

```
auto myhelper = [&]() -> mytask<int> {
  co_await some_event;
  co_return 5;
}();
```

Is the following truly the only way to ensure you're not going to get reallocations?

```
auto myhelper = [&]() -> mytask<int> {
  while (true) {
    co_await some_event;
    co_yield 5;
  }
}();
```

Because I'm structuring all my coroutines this way, and can't even figure out a decent macro or function means to hide that cumbersome loop, nor the boilerplate in general (ie parenthesis after {}).

I am aware of per-promise_type custom allocators, but consider the overhead to be too high (as size may vary, still requires checking free list, still effectively a reallocation, etc).

Comment: *The call to operator new can be optimized out (even if custom allocator is used) if
1. The lifetime of the coroutine state is strictly nested within the lifetime of the caller, and 2.
the size of coroutine frame is known at the call site* - do these apply to your caller?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: He's not talking about eliding the coroutine handle creation. He's talking about keeping the specific coroutine handle around indefinitely, repeatedly re-initializing it via some mechanism.

Comment: @NicolBolas: But if creating the handle can be free, wouldn't it be fine to discard and recreate it each time?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: But he doesn't expect creating the handle to be free. Or at least, there's nothing here in his use case that would suggest such an expectation. In general, if you see `co_await`, you're probably looking at a scenario where handle elision isn't possible.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: In my case co_await registers "myhelper" for resuming externally, which clang sees as a potential lifetime leak necessitating memory allocation.

Thinking on it more, what I think I actually need/desire is the ability to tell the compiler that the coroutine cannot possibly escape the block it is created within.

    `co_await [[clang::noescape]] myhelper();`

If that attribute could guarantee that operator new is elided I'd be able to use regular coroutine structure just fine, giving back the ability to use parameters etc.

Comment: Actually that shouldn't even be necessary - the compiler can of course see that "myhelper" is destroyed at scope exit, and therefore cannot escape. I can see this in the llvm bitcode too, it seems that it prefers to not elide for some reason. I guess something that will improve in time.

Comment: If you're convinced that this is a missed optimization, you should file a Clang bug report for it.

Comment: @Mania: What are you `co_await`ing on, such that the coroutine won't actually leave the scope? And when I say "leave the scope", what that means is that some other thread may resume the coroutine outside of the scope of the receiver of the `mytask`.

Comment: I can see that it is a complicated optimization.

To remove the heap allocation, and nest this coroutine in the frame of the one awaiting on it, the size of the coroutine's frame must be known. That size will depend on what coroutines are in turn nested inside of it, which is a whole nesting-dolls problem that I suspect just hasn't been implemented yet.

So for now, even though some of the coroutine frameworking can be elided, the calls to `new` and `delete` remain. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Consider an async method which has a few helper routines that may yield on an external event a couple of times before returning a value to the outer method. If you wrote them as macros (to force inlining), the compiler would neatly embed them in the outer coroutine. Or, per the hacky workaround above, you can write each "helper" as a `for (;;)` that yield the little bit of work they do, ensuring no allocations throughout the life of the coroutine they're assisting. As it is, repeated use of asynchronous coroutines seems expensive, at least on clang.

Comment: I think I've determined that llvm will not elide across suspend points currently. Crux of it is: llvm's `CoroElidePass` is called _after_ `CoroSplitPass`, which transforms the function in to a switch based state-machine. As a state machine, the `llvm.coro.free` no longer post-dominates the `llvm.coro.begin`, so `shouldElide` returns false. This is despite that the free does post-dominate the alloc in the original CFG. I feel this is likely an overlooked optimization right now, but perhaps this ordering is necessary.

Comment: @Mania: As I suspected, what you clearly want is a fiber. You have multiple levels of "coroutines" that will independently suspend themselves, but the levels are all statically scoped to a specific call stack. That spells "fiber". `co_await` will always be more cumbersome and/or less efficient in those cases because they're not the main situation the feature is designed for.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I think you're right, I will say I see this as being a rather frustrating limitation of C++ coroutines though. Mostly in that the moment you want to factor out _any_ co_await statement, no matter how lightweight, you end up with nested coroutines. eg, virtually any cppcon talk shows the value of lightweight lambdas to give names to blocks of code, yet the same does not translate to coroutines without high expense. It's a shame really, they're just so close to serving my purpose well here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `co_await`-based coroutine mechanism is designed around a very specific usage scenario: you invoke an asynchronous operation and suspend your current function, scheduling its resumption when the asynchronous operation has generated a value. That's the core use case behind the feature. Even generator-based scenarios are just a degenerate form of this, where there is no asynchronous operation, and the future/promise machinery instead gives the caller the power to resume the coroutine.

What you're doing here is not incorrect, in the sense that the coroutine machinery permits you to do this kind of repeated execution of some async operation through a single coroutine future. And if you feel that this is the most efficient way to handle the specific task you're trying to accomplish, you are free to use this method.

But "recycling" coroutine handles isn't really how the system is meant to be used at all. Handles are *meant* to eventually terminate. They are created, exist for a while, wait on some operation(s), schedule their resumption(s), and complete. That's the paradigm.

As such, the designed solution for your problem (avoiding allocating memory) is the provided promise-based allocation machinery. You feel that this isn't good enough, and therefore, you are forced to use less savory, more syntactically ugly mechanisms. That's generally what happens when your needs don't match up well with those provided by a design.

It may simply be a case of your needs not being matched up well with `co_await`-style suspend-up coroutines. Maybe a true fiber would be more useful for your code.